# Notepad++ tab indent code from vertical line, not start of line

Tags: notepad++

Is there a feature in Notepad++ that allows me to draw a vertical line across a few lines of code and then tab from the vertical line instead of from the beginning of each line (which is the default tab behavior)?

I know that UltraEdit has this feature, but not sure about Notepad++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Simply hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, draw a vertical selection with your cursor, then tab.

Comment: brillaint!  that's going to save me a few hours =)